# rails route error undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner of RoR and this is my sample

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def welcome
  end
end
```

in my route file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root :to => “pages#welcome”
...
end
```

when I open powder

[image: http://imgur.com/TFUyPCA]

Comment: `root :to => "pages#welcome"` wrong quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#config/routes.rb    
root to: "pages#welcome"
```